# Flex converting videos on fly?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I ask google about this,but didn't find anything usefull.
Is there a way to creat web app in flex that will convert video to flv,after that video is uploaded to the server?Can this be done with flex,if can,do I still need to install ffmpeg on server?
Tnx for response.

Comment: Note that you can't convert video to flv technically, flv is a container, not a video format.  You can put sorrenson, on2 vp6 or h264 in that container to play in flash.

Comment: ok,tnx @Scott,not sure to understand you,I want for example to convert video.avi to video.flv this can not be done? I will google things that you wrote.Tnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert server side anyway. This will allow you to validate the upload.

Comment: In short yes. You need to run ffmpeg on the server. Every video file that is uploaded should be run through it including uploaded FLVs. This will allow you to standardize the output file to specific sizes and resolutions and whatever else you can think of. Basically giving you full control of the converted video. For example look at youtube if you upload a file there it will be converted. The same thing goes for anytime you have a user uploading a file of any type, you need to validate it . Also help reduce security risks.

Comment: Thanks @The_asMan for response,problem is that I can't install additional software on server.

Comment: Then install another server to do the conversions :)

Comment: so to get a new dedicated server will solve my problem? :) nice,will need to check that,tnx @The_asMan

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the other post that you probably should perform the conversion server side.  Since you don't have a great grasp of the difference between container formats and video formats yet, creating custom client side code might get difficult since you're going to have to get a little closer to the metal.

Given that, there are some people who are doing conversion on the fly client side for certain video formats to FLV within the flash client.  [MKVLoader](http://code.google.com/p/mkvloader/) is a pretty nifty project where they use the new appendBytes(bytes) method that is now available as of Flash 10.1 on the [NetStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#appendBytes%28%29) object to convert MKV to FLV in the client.  This is a really cool trick, but you'll run into problems as soon as you want to support another format.

ffmpeg supports so many formats, it would be silly not to use it.  Since you mention that the video will get to your server anyway, you might as well convert it on the server before storing it.

Comment: Tnx @Scott for response,I will take a look at your links.